# how to Forbidden Wpf DataGrid Click Event making a new line

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I use DataGrid ,because I need to add new line to edit the data, so,I must let the

```
CanUserAddRows="True" .
```

but I found that,when I click the other cell,the dataGrid will build a new Line ,and I don't know how to forbidden the event.and I found that because I binding the "float" or "int" data,the cell will full the cell with "0",what i can do to let it be space without the "0" to full it.so anyone can give me some advise,thank you.[image]

Comment: Why can't you simply set the CanUserAddRows property to false if you want to prevent the new line from appearing? Or how to you intend to show the add row?

Comment: Because I need to add new line ,this page is for me  to add new lines not to show the data.so i can't let CanUserAddRows be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Binding of the DataGridTextColumn to a property of type `int?` instead of `int`. In other words, consider a case in which you have a model with two properties, one of type int and the other int?:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int? _indexNullable;
    public int? IndexNullable { get { return _indexNullable; } set { _indexNullable = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IndexNullable"); } }

    int _index;
    public int Index { get { return _index; } set { _index = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Index"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

You can see the difference in the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" DataContext="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Index}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IndexNullable}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Similarly, if you are using ``float``, change it to be Nullable: ``float?``

Comment: I am very appreciate to you for detailed program.but I am not familiar with MVVM,I just use simple Staff class,'public class Staff
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Test_Score { get; set; }
        public float[] G = new float[100];
    }',and use observableCollection<Staff>,so,it's a little diffult for me to make biggish change .

Comment: and I just change my program like that 'public float? Test_Score { get; set; }',the program will report a error

Comment: ``public float? Test_Score { get; set; }`` must do the job. However, you should change different parts of your program in order to deal with this change. So, wait, maybe others suggest different answers.

Comment: it can't be changed to be float?

Comment: I just feel very so sorry to you ,it,s other place I use the Test_Score and I forgot use (float) to convert float? to float forcely,but when I click other cell,the DataGrid will automaticly add a new line .thank you very much

Comment: I just found that ,only after I double click the last row , then click other row ,the dataGrid will add a new line.I just think ,the DataGrid will define consider that i must add the content to the last row after double click envent.